# Why is the rowIndex property of a jQuery returned element.parents("tr") row undefined?

Tags: jquery

If i get a reference to an elements parent as follows:

```
function findParentRow(srcElement) {
    var curElement = srcElement;
    while (curElement && (curElement.tagName != "TR")) {
        curElement = curElement.parentElement;
    }
    return (curElement.tagName == 'TR' ? curElement : null);
}
```

I can:

```
var parentRow = findParentRow(someElement);
alert(parentRow.rowIndex);
```

and I will get a rowIndex alert. But if i:

```
var parentRow = $(chkBox).parents("tr");
```

I can

```
alert(parentRow);
```

and get an object but if i

```
alert(parentRow.rowIndex);
```

I get undefined. Instead i have too:

```
alert($(pRow).attr("rowIndex"));
```

to get an index.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `parentRow` is now a jQuery object... use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) instead of `rowIndex`..

try [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) also instead of `.parents()`,..

```
var parentRow = $(chkBox).closest("tr");
alert(parentRow.index());
```

Comment: Just to add to your answer, the key concept for me was the idea of 'wrapped sets". Once i got that everything else fell into place. I fail to see why they arent mentioned in the jQuery.com "How it works" tutorial.